# Expected winning of a player with highest lowest and second highest lowest grouping

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

The following is an interview question.

> Question:     Given 4 players $A,B,C,D$ and a fair $50$-sided dice, assume that we do not allow repeated score (i.e. next player cannot get the same score as all previous players. Otherwise, the player roll again).
>
> We group players with the highest and lowest scores together and second and third highest together. The winning team is the group that has the larger sum which will win the difference between team score.
>
> For example, say $A,B$ and $C,D$ form 2 groups and $A=1,B=7,C=3,D=2,$ then $A,B$ groups wins with $8-5=3$ units.
>
> What number should player $A$ hopes to get to maximize his expected winning?

I totally have no idea how to start this question at all.

Comment: Some (possibly relevant) observations:  for a $4$ sided die it makes no difference what  $A$ chooses...the game is always a tie.  For a $5$ sided die the non-ties are $\{1,2,3, 5\}$ and $\{1,3,4,5\}$ so  $A$ could choose any of $\{1,3,4,5\}$ but now $2$ would be a bad choice (no winning team can have $2$ on it.)

Comment: Interestingly, for a $6-$sided die, choosing $6$ seems sub-optimal.  The only winning games for the $6$ holder are $\{6,1,2,3\},\,\{6,1,2,4\}$ whereas the $5$ holder wins with $\{6,2,4,5\},\,\{6,1,3,5\},\,\{6,1,4,5\},\,\{5,1,2,3\}$.  Trusting that no error was made, of course.

Comment: @lulu I also had the same observation when I was asked this question. However, I couldn't solve the original in the end.

Comment: You could do the continuous case.  Replace the numbers $1$ to $50$ with the interval $[0,1]$, and set up a triple integral.  Take $w\lt x\lt y\lt z$. I would separate out the income when you turn out to be  $w$, or $z$, or the other two.

Comment: $50$ is large enough that Empy2's idea is probably a good approximation, and one consequence is you shouldn't pick to top number.  If you do, you can expect the other three numbers to be (on average) at the $25$th, $50$th, and $75$th percentiles, so you picking the top number would lead to a tie game on average.  You can do better by picking $49$.  Conditioned on your $49$ being top, it's still a tie game on average, but if someone rolled $50$, you're in for a killing since the other two numbers will be $33$rd and $66$th percentiles on average.  Picking $48$ is likely even better, you have...

Comment: [cont'd] even better chance that your $48$ will be the second highest number, while running a tiny risk of you being the third highest number.  Intuitively and very vaguely, I feel you want to pick a high number which has a decent chance of becoming the second highest...

Comment: @Idonknow - the OP said the winning team wins the difference, but does the losing team have to lose the difference, or does the losing team simply gain and lose nothing?  I.e. is the winning team's profit paid by the losing team, or by a third-party bank?  This makes quite a difference to the expected value calculation.

Comment: This problem is quite intriguing, and it would be helpful if someone could explain the steps to derive the quartic function in @Empy2's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The triple integral for the continuous case comes to 
$$\frac18(1-x)^4 + x^3(1-x) + \frac18x^4$$
Its local maximum is near $x=0.86$.
The three terms are for $x=a$, $x=b \text{ or }c$ and $x=d$.
 Alex's numbers follow one quartic for $n=1$ to $25$, and a different quartic for $n=26$ to $50$.

Comment: The [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho1rG.png) of the considered function.

Comment: Hi @Empy2, thank you for your answer! How did you get $1/8$ in front of the first and third terms?

Comment: I was initially confused because if $x$ is the smallest number rolled, then the expected payoff would be $\mathbb{E}[(x_{(4)}+x - (x_{(3)}+x_{(2)}))] = \mathbb{E}[(x_{(4)} - x_{(3)}) - (x_{(2)} - x)] = 0$. I was just curious about how you arrived at the value of 1/8. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: A factor of 6 for the ranking of the other three, then (for the largest) triple integral c=0 to x,b=0 to c,a=(0 or b+c-x) to b, 1 da db dc

Comment: If c is less than $x/2$ then you can ignore b+c-x because it is negative, otherwise break [0,c]db into [0,x-c]db +[x=c,c]db

Answer (score 4):

The question can be easily answered by a short computer program. Below are provided a graph and a table of the total gain (divided by $6$) for each choice $a_1$ of the first player. The best choice is $a_1=43$ with the total gain $139940\cdot 6$.

[image]

```
110400
101476
93150
85441
78365
71935
66161
61050
56606
52830
49720
47271
45475
44321
43795
43880
44556
45800
47586
49885
52665
55891
59525
63526
67850
72450
77280
82295
87447
92685
97955
103200
108360
113372
118170
122685
126845
130575
133797
136430
138390
139590
139940
139347
137715
134945
130935
125580
118772
110400
```

The program (in Pascal):

```
program p3542562;
const
 n=50;
var
 OFi:Text;
 a1,a2,a3,a4,gain:LongInt;
 w:array[1..n]of LongInt;
begin
assign(OFi,'3542562.txt');
Rewrite(OFi);
for a1:=1 to n do begin
 w[a1]:=0;
 for a2:=1 to n-2 do for a3:=a2+1 to n-1 do for a4:=a3+1 to n do begin
  if (a1<>a2) and (a1<>a3) and (a1<>a4) then begin
   if a1>a4 then gain:=a1+a2-a3-a4 else
   if a1<a2 then gain:=a1+a4-a2-a3 else
    gain:=a1+a3-a2-a4;
   if gain>0 then w[a1]:=w[a1]+gain;
  end;
 end;
 writeln(OFi,w[a1]);
end;
Close(OFi);
end.
```

---

Below are provided a graph and a table of the total gain (divided by $6$) for each choice $a_1$ of the first player *for the case when the winning team gain is paid by the losing team. The best choice now is $a_1=40$ with the total gain $86710\cdot 6$.

[image]

```
0
-17296
-32430
-45494
-56580
-65780
-73186
-78890
-82984
-85560
-86710
-86526
-85100
-82524
-78890
-74290
-68816
-62560
-55614
-48070
-40020
-31556
-22770
-13754
-4600
4600
13754
22770
31556
40020
48070
55614
62560
68816
74290
78890
82524
85100
86526
86710
85560
82984
78890
73186
65780
56580
45494
32430
17296
0
```

Comment: In the line "gain:=a2+a4-a1-a3", should it be "gain:=a1+a3-a2-a4" instead?  I'm guessing the gain is from the perspective of a1, right?

Comment: @antkam Oops, I corrected the answer. Thanks.

Comment: +1 :) 43 is more intuitive. In my comments to the main thread, I felt the optimal is a high number but not the top number. Glad to see the actual numerical result agrees with my gut feel. BTW, since you have the code already -- do you mind trying the case when the losing team has to lose money? I.e. instead of "if gain>0 then w[a1] := w[a1]+gain", simply have "w[a1] := w[a1]+gain" (i.e. even if gain<0). I understand the OP wording favors the "losing team loses nothing" interpretation, but I wonder if the alternate "losing team loses the difference" variant has a different result.  Thanks!

Comment: @antkam I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If player $A$ scores $50$ and his team mate scores $1$, their team scores $51$. So the second and third highest players should not score more than $24 + 25 = 49$, thus allowing for $(25-1) \times (24-1) = 24 \times 23 = 552$ possibilities.

If player $A$ scores $50$ and his team mate scores $2$, their team scores $52$. So the second and third highest players should not score more than $25 + 26 = 49$, thus allowing for $25 \times 24 = 600$ possibilities.

Continuing in this way, if player $A$ scores $50$ and his teammate scores $46$, their team scores $50 + 46 = 96$, and then the second and third highest-scoring player can score at most $48 + 47 = 95$, thus allowing for $$47 \times 46$ possibilities.

Comment: So player $A$ should choose $50?$

Comment: The answer requires a much more calculations and even the number of winning combinations should be counted more carefully. Even if player $A$ scores $50$ and his team mate scores $1$, the number of pairs of distinct integers $i,j\in [2,49]$ with $i+j\le 50$ is $$\sum_{i=2}^{48} \sum_{j=2}^{50-i} 1 – \sum_{i=1}^{24} 1=\sum_{i=2}^{48} (49-i )  – 24=\sum_{k=1}^{47} k  – 24=47\cdot 48/2-24=46\cdot 24=1104.$$ But the total gain of $A$ and his team mate is counted as $$\sum_{i=2}^{48} \sum_{j=2}^{50-i} (50+1-i-j) – \sum_{i=1}^{24} (50+1-2i).$$